# MySQL PDO, selecting a single row from a result-set

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I run a query that returns multiple rows, is there a way I can select just one row out of that result?

So if I do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number = 10
```

and it returns 33 results, is there a way I can go through those one at a time instead of returning the whole result set at once, or just return, for example, row 5 of the result set?

I have read about scrollable cursors but it seems they don't work on MySQL, although that seems to be what I am looking for....

I am using PDO with MySQL and PHP. I hope this makes sense, if not I will try and explain better.

*Edit*: This worked for what I wanted. Thanks.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user_points = '$target' ORDER BY tdate DESC LIMIT $count,1");
```

Comment: Sorry, I did't bother to post code because it was nothing more than a simple select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way I can select just one row out of that result?

Yes there is, you can use [LIMIT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number = 10 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Wow that was so simple I was looking for a much more complicated solution! This what exactly what I needed. I just used a variable for the limit number that I can pass along with it.

Comment: @Chris simplicity is the key :) if my answer helped you , please consider accepting it as the correct one, tks !

Comment: Just did, you answered so quick it wouldn't let me yet :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user_points = '$target' ORDER BY tdate";

$stmt= $pdo -> prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt ->fetchAll();
//You asked about getting a specific row 5
//rows begin with 0. Now $data2 contains row 5
$data2 = $data[4];
echo $data2['A_column_in_your_table'];//row 5 data
```